# displaying ACF repeater fields as shordcode in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a wordpress and ACF related question.
I need to display repeater field as a shortcode that will be created inside functions.php file.
Then I will use shortcode inside post page with Gutenberg.
Is this possible?

I struggle with this today and I can`t find a solution :(

```
<?php if ( have_rows( 'car_parts' ) ) : ?>  /* this is repeater field */
    <?php while ( have_rows( 'car_parts' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
        <?php the_sub_field( 'car_engine' ); ?>  /* this is repeater subfield */
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php // No rows found ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I prepared a function called

```
function get_car_parts() {
    echo 'display ACF repeater fields here';
}
    
add_shortcode( 'show-car-parts', 'get_car_parts' );
```

Any help greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback in add_shortcode function should not return an output of any kind, just return the text that is to be used to replace the shortcode, like this:

```
<?php
function get_car_parts()
{
  if (have_rows('car_parts')): /* this is repeater field */
    while (have_rows('car_parts')):
        the_row();
        $car_engine = the_sub_field('car_engine'); /* this is repeater subfield */
   endwhile;
    return $car_engine;
  else:
    return "No rows found";
  endif;
}

add_shortcode('show-car-parts', 'get_car_parts');
```

Comment: thank you very much :-) now everything is working! I`ve learn the lesson :-) Have a nice day!